# Freeform - adding an option to my form edit page

Tags: forms, solspace-freeform

I need any form I create to belong to a parent category.
The categories can be hard coded, but I need to know where/how to save that selection and how to show it on edit form page.

I've added the select box to edit_form.html and it's showing, but how to save that data I'm not sure about. In the SQL there's a 'settings' field, can I save custom data like this, there?

I can create a new column sure, but I'd like to avoid hacking the established structure if I can... Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly your question, I would suggest you to create a new form field (from FreeForm module area in CP) and store category value with that.

On the entries listing of any Form, you can see button "Edit Field Layout" and you can include that category field into "Shown Fields".

**Note**: You should have FreeForm v4.0+ for above.

Comment: not quite, I want to edit the 'master form' form. I have made several custom form elements, but now I need to add a new field to the form I see when I create a new form... that's confusing :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you if you are creating form and form field properly.

Comment: I can create forms using the module, I'm all happy there.. I want to be able to add a new option to the 'create a new form' page, the one that uses the HTML from edit_form.html. I've added a field on that page, but want to know where to save that data... OR, is there a better way?